# Deploy to vnet from Azure devops

Tags: azure-functions, azure-pipelines, azure-logic-apps, vnet

I want to deploy using devops several vnet enabled Logic apps standard and an Azure function.

What do I need to do to accomplish this besides creating a virtual machine with my self hosted agent in the same vnet as the logic apps / function?

Is it enough that my virtual vm and my logic apps/function are in the same virtual network or must I create a private link or a service endpoint to deploy to vnet?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please add some (relevant) logic flow and approaches, as it's very hard answering your question in its current form. Explain what you tried and why that didn't work. Please refer to [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: `What do I need to do to accomplish this besides creating a virtual machine with my self hosted agent in the same vnet as the logic apps / function?` this should be enough. But best way is t try and learn